# RDP stuck with old Windows 10 password

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I've changed Microsoft account password. Now Windows 10 uses the new password.

But RDP only logs in with the old password. How do I make RDP use the new password? What might have allowed RDP/Windows 10 passwords get out of sync?

Comment: RDP is to connect to another system. (a) Did you use the Microsoft Live web page to change your password - verify that? (b) Did you change the password the same way on the system you are connecting to? (c) Did you restart both systems?

Comment: @John Changed the Microsoft password online, Windows complained, then I verified the account. Now Windows 10 login screen accepts new password, but RDP (used from a Mac) only accepts the old one.

Comment: Microsoft Live should not complain when you change a password (I have done this).  Make sure the system you are changing has a valid PIN, log in, change the password again to something different. Then again reboot Windows 10 and the MAC.

Comment: @John Changing password online worked and this time Windows 10 didn't complain. After reboot, RDP password synced to Windows 10/Microsoft account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Live should not complain when you change a password (I have done this).

So do a another full change of password.

Make sure the system you are changing has a valid PIN, log in, change the password again to something different. Then again reboot Windows 10 and the MAC.

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Credential Manager on the remote machine keeps the RDP password in its local cache.

### Solution

Removing the credentials there, forces RDP to verify the password online:

- Open the Windows Credential Manager on the remote machine
- Select the 'Web Credentials' tab
- Remove the cached credentials for the account you use to logon to the remote machine. On my machine, the entry was named `Terminal` and was linked to the `onmicrosoft.com` domain

[image: Windows 10 Credential Manager]

### Workaround

Alternatively, you can use this workaround that I came up with in 2016: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/force-refresh-sync-of-microsoft-account-password/d7bddb0d-663f-4775-9593-ce21b17ca800

Connect with and log in to a different account (e.g. the built-in `Administrator` account), and run the following command in a command prompt on the remote machine:

`runas /u:MicrosoftAccount\[Microsoft Email Address] cmd.exe`

This will force Windows to request your new credentials and update the cached passwords in the Credential Manager.

I personally prefer the workaround, since I can put that command in a script on my desktop and execute it when needed.

Comment: How many YEARs I had problems with old AzureAD passwords! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
Open a cmd.exe

runas /user:MicrosoftAccount[EmailAdress] cmd.exe

this seems to update the local cache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could at least have given me the credit for posting this workaround already in 2016 instead of copy/pasting 1 line from it: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/force-refresh-sync-of-microsoft-account-password/d7bddb0d-663f-4775-9593-ce21b17ca800